# How to create database in postgresql in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

how i can create database in ubuntu 16.04 using postgresql ? 
atfer creation of database,at which place it will be saved ? 
And How to create table in ubuntu 16.04 using postgresql ? 
Is any software is available to work with postgresql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
first way is:<br>
   CREATE DATABASE dbname;

for example:<br>
    postgres=# CREATE DATABASE testdb;<br>
    postgres-# 

 Second way is:<br>
     createdb command<br>

    **for example:**<br>
       createdb -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres testdb
```